# Ansible mysql_query: How to handle if else logic or dependent queries

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using community.mysql.mysql_query module to run some queries against my DB using Ansible.

I'm trying to perform single transaction reads using multiple queries (SELECT statements) where every query has unique conditions (FROM and WHERE).

The issue that I'm running into is that some SELECT statements executions are dependent on others. For instance:

```
- name: "Read User Name"
    community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{login_host}}"
        login_db: "{{login_db}}"
        query:
            - >-
            SELECT username AS user_name
            FROM table1 WHERE user_id = 1
    register: user_name_reg

- name: "Set User Name"
    set_fact:
        user_name: "{{ user_name_reg['query_result'][0][0]['user_name'] }}"

- name: "Read User Last Name"
    community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{login_host}}"
        login_db: "{{login_db}}"
        query:
            - >-
            SELECT userLastName AS user_last_name
            FROM table2 WHERE user_name = "{{ user_name }}"
    register: user_last_name_reg
```

or some logic is present, as follows:

```
# Pseudocode

# user_name = query_result("
# SELECT username AS user_name
# FROM table1 WHERE user_id = 1")

# if not user_name:
#    user_name = query_result("
#    SELECT username AS user_name
#    FROM table2 WHERE user_special_id = 1")

- name: "Read User Name 1st"
    community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{login_host}}"
        login_db: "{{login_db}}"
        query:
            - >-
            SELECT username AS user_name
            FROM table1 WHERE user_id = 1
    register: user_name_reg

- name: "Set User Name"
    set_fact:
        user_name: "{{ user_name_reg['query_result'][0][0]['user_name'] }}"

- name: "Read User Name 2nd"
    community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{login_host}}"
        login_db: "{{login_db}}"
        query:
            - >-
            SELECT username AS user_name
            FROM table2 WHERE user_special_id = 1
    register: user_name2_reg
    when: "user_name = NULL"
```

I think my examples are not transaction safe, as there is no locking mechanism between tasks.

My questions are as follow:

1. Is there any way to handle the above use cases using mysql_query module (as a single transaction)?
2. If not, would it make more sense to implement the two uses cases using SQL scripts or action modules for ansible?

Comment: That Ansible can run queries in MySQL is both amazing and terrifying.

Comment: I get the amazing, but not the terrifying @tadman